# How to configure .ebextensions for nginx location directive?

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to configure my staging environment in Elastic Beanstalk to always disallow all spiders. The nginx directive would look like this:

```
location /robots.txt {
    return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /";
}
```

I understand that I would want to create a file under the .ebextensions/ folder, such as 01_nginx.config, but I'm not sure how to structure the YAML inside it such that it would work. My goal is to add this location directive to existing configuration, not have to fully replace any existing configuration files which are in place.

Answer (score 15):

There is an approach which uses the more recent `.platform/nginx` configuration extension on Amazon Linux 2 (as opposed to older AMIs).

The default `nginx.conf` includes configuration partials in two locations of the overall `nginx.conf` file. One is immediately inside the `http` block, so you can't place additional `location` blocks here, because that's not syntactically legal. The second is inside the `server` block, though, and that's what we need.

This second location's partial files are included from a special sub-directory, `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk`. Place your location fragment here to add location blocks, like so:

```
# .platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/packs.conf
location /packs {
    alias /var/app/current/public/packs;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

You find this in the documentation under [Reverse Proxy Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.proxy.nginx).

Comment: Do you still need to do a container_command to replace/remove the default file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf`?

Comment: what would be the logic if I want to override events directive? `events {
    worker_connections  6144;
}
`

Comment: This is by far the best solution. It makes proper use of the line: `include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. For future travellers, you can confirm that the file is copied to the expected directory successfully by running `eb ssh` and then `ls -al /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/`.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to do the same thing. After a lot of digging, I found 2 ways to do it:

## Option 1. Use an ebextension to replace the nginx configuration file with your custom configuration

I used this option because it is the simplest one.

Following the example given by Amazon in [Using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Node.js Platform - Configuring the Proxy Server - Example .ebextensions/proxy.config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html), we can see that they create an ebextension that creates a file named **/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf**. This file contains the same content as the original nginx configuration file. Then, they delete the original nginx configuration file using **container_commands**.

You need to replace the Amazon example with the contents of your current nginx configuration file. Note that the nginx configuration files to be deleted in the containter command must be updated too. The ones I used are:

- **nginx configuration file 1**: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf
- **nginx configuration file 2**: /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf

Therefore, the final ebextension that worked for me is as follows:

**/.ebextensions/nginx_custom.config**

```yaml
# Remove the default nginx configuration generated by elastic beanstalk and
# add a custom configuration to include the custom location in the server block.
# Note that the entire nginx configuration was taken from the generated /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf file
# and then, we just added the extra location we needed.

files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_custom.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream my_app {
        server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
      }

      log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                      '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                      '$http_x_forwarded_for';

      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          set $year $1;
          set $month $2;
          set $day $3;
          set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /assets {
          alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location /public {
          alias /var/app/current/public;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location /robots.txt {
          return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /";
        }
      }

container_commands:
  # Remove the default nginx configuration generated by elastic beanstalk
 removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf"
```

Once you deploy this change, you have to reload the nginx server. You can connect to your server using **eb ssh your-environment-name** and then run **sudo service nginx reload**

## Option 2. Use an ebextension to modify the nginx configuration file generator, so that it includes your custom locations in the final nginx configuration file

The second option is based on this post: [jabbermarky's answer in Amazon forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228527)

He explains this method very well in his answer, so I encourage you to read it if you want to implement it. If you are going to implement this answer, you need to update the location of the nginx file configuration generator.

Note that I have not tested this option.

In summary, he adds a shell script to be executed before the nginx configuration file is generated. In this shell script, he modifies the nginx configuration file generator to include the server block locations he wants in the generated nginx configuration file. Finally, he adds a file containing the locations he wants in the server block of the final nginx configuration file.

Comment: For those who use latest EB platform, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812541/3090068 is the correct answer, as the nginx configuration is managed by Elastic Beanstalk and manual configurations done in `.ebextensions` gets wiped out.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the mentioned approaches dont work anymore. The new approach is to place nginx .conf files into a subfolder in .ebextensions:

> You can now place an nginx.conf file in the **.ebextensions/nginx** folder to override the Nginx configuration. You can also place configuration files in the **.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d** folder in order to have them included in the Nginx configuration provided by the platform.

[Source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-beanstalk-update-support-for-java-and-go/)

This does not require a restart of nginx either as Elastic Beanstalk will take care of that.

Comment: I read somewhere else that this only works on certain platforms, maybe not Docker platforms. Double check the platform you're using.

Comment: This only seems to be documented for the Java platform.

Answer (score 3):

Mmmmm! `.ebextensions`!

You're probably easiest off creating a shell script to change your configuration, and then running that. Don't really know nginx, but try something along the lines of:

```
files:
    "/root/setup_nginx.sh" :
    mode: "000750"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        #!/bin/sh
        #  Configure for NGINX
        grep robots.txt <your_config_file> > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then
            echo < EOF >> <your_config_file>
            location /robots.txt {
                return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /";
            }
            EOF
        # Restart any services you need restarting
        fi

container_commands:
    000-setup-nginx:
        command: /root/setup_nginx.sh
```

I.e. first create a schell script that does what you need, then run it.

Oh, and be careful there are no tabs in your YAML! Only spaces are allowed... Check the log file `/var/log/cfn_init.log` for errors...

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

For version Amazon Linux 2 use this path on your bundle and zip this foldes together

.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/000_my_custom.conf

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is what's working for me:

```
files:
   "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_syncserver.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # 10/7/17; See https://github.com/crspybits/SyncServerII/issues/35
      client_max_body_size 100M;
      # SyncServer uses some http request headers with underscores
      underscores_in_headers on;
      # 5/20/21; Trying to get the load balancer to respond with a 503
      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier
        location / {
          return 503;
        }
      }

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: pgrep nginx && service nginx reload || true
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this - you need to wrap your configuration file. You should have, if you're using Docker, a zip file (mine is called `deploy.zip`) that contains your `Dockerrun.aws.json`. If you don't - it's rather easy to modify, just zip your deploy via
`zip -r deploy.zip Dockerrun.aws.json`

With that - you now need to add a `.platform` folder as follows:

```
├── .platform
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── custom.conf
```

You can name your `custom.conf` whatever you want, and can have as many files as you want. Inside `custom.conf`, you simply need to place the following inside

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Or whatever you want for your config. With that - modify your zip to now be

`zip -r deploy.zip Dockerrun.aws.json`

And deploy. Your Nginx server will now respect the new command

Answer (score -1):

This is achievable using .ebextension config files, however I'm having difficulty kicking nginx to restart after a change to its configuration files.

```
# .ebextensions/nginx.config
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/robots.conf":
    mode: "000544"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      location /robots.txt {
        return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /";
      }
    encoding: plain
```

Now, I've done similar to add a file to kick the nginx tyres, however for some odd reason it's not executing:

```
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/03_restart_nginx.sh":
  mode: "000755"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars
    sudo service nginx restart
    ps aux | grep nginx > /home/ec2-user/nginx.times.log
    true
  encoding: plain
```

Comment: Actually I tried this and it totally failed. From the logs:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2014/05/09 11:46:09 [emerg] 13740#0: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/robots.conf:1
2014/05/09 11:46:11 [emerg] 13746#0: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/robots.conf:1
```

Comment: Oh bugger. Yeah, ok, evidently that cannot be achieved globally.

You'll need to actually find & replace the content within the nginx configuration file itself. It's a little harder but still achievable.