# Nginx config file overwritten during Elastic Beanstalk deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to add p3p headers to the static resource location on a standard Nodejs & Nginx Elastic Beanstalk.

I've created an `ebextension` script as explained on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335575/how-to-configure-ebextensions-for-nginx-location-directive/21336573#21336573). The script uses set to add a `add_header` directive under the `alias` line, which is under the static location directive. It runs on the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` file.

The script not only modifies the file, it also copies it to a "safe" location, i.e. /home/ec2-user. According to `/var/log/cfn-init.log`, the script runs correctly. As evidence, the copy of the modified file shows the additional header at the right place. But the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` file **does not have this modification**.

I can only deduce that although my script runs fine, something else later in the deployment process overwrites it. Which is strange, because [according to documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) container commands are run after the application and web server have been set up, so I don't see what does it.

So ho/what is overwriting this file and how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that Elastic Beanstalk has changed and the commonly recommended approach/hack of overwriting `#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` doesn't work any more. Nor does creating *any* file in /tmp/deployment/config.

The solution I found was to overwrite `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` directly, using a ***container_commands*** directive, since these commands are executed after the Elastic Beanstalk install creates it's version of the nginx config.

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands:

> They [container_commands] run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version file has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed.

I did this in three steps within .ebextensions:

1. Create my version of the nginx config file.
2. Create a script to overwrite the standard config file with my own.
3. Run the script.

The first two steps happen earlier in the install process, while the last uses *container_commands* so as described previous happens late in the install.

Here's the files I used:

**File .ebextensions/install_nginx_config_01.config**:
(Note that the indenting is important)

```
#
#   STEP 1 - Create the nginx config file
#
files:

  "/tmp/my.nginx.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # This file was overwritten during deployment
      # by .ebextensions/install_nginx_config_03.config

      upstream nodejs {
          server 127.0.0.1:3000;
          keepalive 256;
      }

      server {
          listen 8080;

          location / {
              proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
              proxy_set_header   Connection "";
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
              proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          }

          gzip on;
          gzip_comp_level 4;
          gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
      }
```

**File .ebextensions/install_nginx_config_02.config**:

```
#
#   STEP 2 - Create a script that will overwrite the Nginx config
#
files:

  "/tmp/install-nginx-config.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      cp /tmp/my.nginx.conf /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```

**File .ebextensions/install_nginx_config_03.config**:

```
#
#   STEP 3 - Run the script to overwrite the nginx config template.
#
container_commands:

  01_runmyshellscript:
    command: "/tmp/install-nginx-config.sh"
```

Comment: this seems to be the only thing that works as of now

Comment: When I try this I get: Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:[/Resources/AWSEBAutoScalingGroup/Metadata/AWS::CloudFormation::Init/prebuild_1_Homepage/files//tmp/install-nginx-config.sh] 'null' values are not allowed in templates

Comment: Thanks! I finally got this working using this method. It can be noted that all three steps can be put in a single file if one prefers it that way (both files to be written has to be under a single files clause in that case).

Answer (score 27):

After spending almost entire day and trying out all the possible solutions, as of **July 17, 2017**, the above solution does not work.
For me, I wanted to replace /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf
I created the below shown folder structure in my .ebextension folder and the file was overwritten with my content. This solution also worked for nginx.conf which is located in /etc/nginx folder
[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. This behavior is documented [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/category/aws-elastic-beanstalk/).

_You can now place an nginx.conf file in the .ebextensions/nginx folder to override the Nginx configuration. You can also place configuration files in the .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d folder in order to have them included in the Nginx configuration provided by the platform._

Comment: A direct link to the blogpost mentioning the behavior is https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-beanstalk-update-support-for-java-and-go/

Comment: It is worth to mention that this solution work only with some ELB Platforms - Java and Go. If you use for example Docker Platform with nginx as proxy you have to use solution with configuration file (that use **files** keyword) placed inside **.ebextensions** - example below
 `files: "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf":
    content: |
      #your override nginx config here`

Comment: @rkarczmarczyk Actually when I tried to use with docker, I was unable to override any files in /etc/nginx folder. I was however able to override in sites_enabled. I will give your solution a shot. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I can confirm this is not working with their latest node platform at the time of writing this.

Comment: can you tell how you made changes to the file

Comment: I can confirm that it's working as of March 2019 for the Go platform

Comment: Yeaa! Works for me!

Comment: Placing in `./platform/nginx/*` for Ruby Amazon Linux 2 works. Stated in docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html.

Answer (score 13):

As of this writing, the proper way to update/add values into the **http** config in the `nginx.conf` file **without overwriting it** is to add a `.config` file to the `.ebextensions` folder that looks like this:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom_nginx.conf":
    content: |

      proxy_connect_timeout       600;
      proxy_send_timeout          600;
      proxy_read_timeout          600;
      send_timeout                600;
```

This creates a new file called `custom_nginx.conf` in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory. Since the `nginx.conf` file contains

```
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

when the server is started it will pull the 4 timeout vars from `custom_nginx.conf` into the http section of `nginx.conf`

Comment: can you help me how can I overwrite the nginx.conf file. I need to add http{underscores_in_headers on;}

Comment: At the time of writing this, the `nginx.conf` file is actually located here: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 8):

As of August, 2020 for `Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.0`:

Placing `nginx` files in the `.platform/nginx/` works for me.

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: After spending a day on this, this is the only thing that has worked for me. `ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux] Amazon Linux 2`

Comment: The AWS documentation covers it here:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

See the section titled "Reverse proxy configuration" for details.

Comment: I  actually love you <3

Answer (score 4):

To modify the config file without it being overwritten, the solution is to modify the template file located at `/tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`

I update this file instead to add the desired directive, and it is automatically deployed to `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, and *voila*, the modification is active.

Comment: Are there any different ways other than modifying this file through `files:` block inside a config file located in `.ebextensions` folder? The file is never modified although everything seems to be correct. I just see the default file at both `/tmp/deployment/config` folder and also at `/etc/nginx/` folder.

Comment: Yes, you can run code with the `commands` or `container_commands` sections of the config file. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html.

Comment: `files:` doesn't work.`04modify_nginx_conf:
   command: sed -i '/EB_INCLUDE/a geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;\ngeoip_city /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat;' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#nginx.conf` doesn't work. `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` never changes! I'm really pissed off.

Comment: What if you try to put your configuration in a separate file, like `00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`?

Comment: It should be inside `http` block. And I also tried to modify `00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` but couldn't do that. It turns out creating a bash script and running is the only way to change those files? Doesn't it?

Comment: That's strange, I am updating it with container commands. Here's my config file: http://pastebin.com/aFVAsibh

Comment: Thank you for sharing your config. I've tried creating a config file and doing a `cp -R` to the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` but now I get permission denied error..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95329/discussion-between-antoine-and-scaryguy).

Comment: This no longer works.  @philip-callender comment is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the latest instructions from Amazon, as of August 2018:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html

(I have just used these instructions to customize the Nginx proxy for a Node.js app on Elastic Beanstalk, and it works as expected.)

Basically you use your own proxy.conf for Nginx, and remove the auto-generated stuff.

```
# .ebextensions/proxy.config
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
        keepalive 256;
      }

      server {
        listen 8080;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location /static {
            alias /var/app/current/static;
        }

      }

  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      service nginx stop 
      service nginx start

container_commands:
 removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```