# How to fix 'Health checks failed with these codes: ' on elasticbeanstalk instace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My application has Health Status of Severe because of Target.ResponseCodeMismatch error.

I've tried following **Redirection is not configured on the backend** in this [aws instruction](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-classic-health-checks/) . And I've changed my **port to '443'** and my **protocol to 'HTTPS'** on eb config and redeployed. It changes the Health Status to Ok but when I access my url I get the page 'Index of' only

Here is what `eb status --verbose` returns:

```
Description: Health checks failed with these codes: [301]
Reason: Target.ResponseCodeMismatch
```

And this is from `eb config`:

```
AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener.aws:elbv2:listener:default:
  DefaultProcess: default
  ListenerEnabled: 'true'
  Protocol: HTTP
  Rules: null
  SSLCertificateArns: null
  SSLPolicy: null
AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener443.aws:elbv2:listener:443:
  DefaultProcess: default
  ListenerEnabled: 'true'
  Protocol: HTTPS
  Rules: null
  SSLCertificateArns: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:XXXX:certificate/XXXXXX
  SSLPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-XX-XX-XXXX  
aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
  DeregistrationDelay: '20'
  HealthCheckInterval: '15'
  HealthCheckPath: /      
  HealthCheckTimeout: '5'
  HealthyThresholdCount: '3'
  MatcherHTTPCode: null
  Port: '443'
  Protocol: HTTPS
```

Answer (score 43):

For someone that may come across this as I did, I found the solution to be **setting up the Health Check endpoint of the ELB target group to an actual URL on my website that returned an HTTP 200 code**.

On the EC2 dashboard, under Load Balancing -> Target Groups, go to the tab Health Checks and edit the path to a path in your site that returns an 200 code.

[image]

Comment: CAVEAT for anyone getting an unexpected "Health checks failed with these codes: [301]" message from the health check status details:

Some servers will respond to a directory endpoint which doesn't end in `/` with a 301 redirect to the _same_ endpoint but with the trailing `/`. 

Example: You set up the health check to test `/docs` for a 200, but you get a failing health check due to a 301 response, try changing the health check path to `/docs/` instead of adding 301 to the list of valid status codes.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem. In my case the fix was to change the health check's "Success codes" setting from `200` to `200,301`.

Comment: Thank you @jason for this valuable comment. Your comment saved me. :-)

Comment: This was the solution for me, I have tried to change the path but in my server that is not enough because I need redirections for about 50% of my content to other AWS services

Comment: Some servers will respond with a 301 if you entered a directory endpoint without a trailing slash, such as `/docs` or `/healthcheck`. It will simply redirect you to `/docs/` or `/healthcheck/`, respectively.

So instead of adding 301 to the list of accepted status codes, in this case, you can simply change the health check path from `/docs` to `/docs/` (for example).

Answer (score 1):

In DotNet I added this controller that will allow anonymous access and then in EC2 > Load Balancing > Target Group set the health check path to /health

```
public class HealthController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok($"HEALTH: OK - {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

[image]

Under Advanced Settings, include the HTTP code 302 to the expected results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically your app is going to get deploy exposing it's native port.  In the case of java this is usually 8080, with node it's 3000.  Then AWS will, as part of EB, will still a proxy of either apache or nginx in front of your app exposing port 80. It's ELB that exposes port 443 to the outside.

So you probably want to change the port and protocol to 80 / HTTP

Answer (score 0):

This seem to have helped me, in

"health check settings" > "Advanced health check settings"

Under: "Port" from "Traffic port" to "Override" and used "80"

Under: "Success codes"

One Instance of EB
from "200" to "200,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308" (In Elastic Beanstalk Health was down because of "3xx Responses")

Second Instance of EB
from "200" to "200,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,422,425,426,428,429,431,451" (In Elastic Beanstalk Health was down because of "4xx Responses")

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was as simple as making sure the route that the health check is pointed to, like '/' for my example, returns a 200 result.

```
const router = require("express").Router();

// Health Check
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendStatus(200);
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

after exploring a lot of stuff, the answer is quite simple, you just have to go to
"EC2 =>Target groups => instance which causing issue => Edit health check settings"
and then just have to add an api with slash e.g (/login) which return 200 response, or you can create a new api for it specifically

```
@app.route('/login')
def index():
    return 'OK', 200
```

[as per below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXfmw.png)

Answer (score -3):

I had the following problem:

```
Description: Health checks failed with these codes: [400]
Reason: Target.ResponseCodeMismatch
```

What fixed for me was entering the `Success codes` value to `400`.

EC2 (service) > Load Balancing (from left side menu) > Target Groups (click on Name) > Health Check (click on tab) > Edit > Advanced health check settings > Success codes = 400

Comment: Yes, this would fix the problem, but since an HTTP 400 error code denotes a failure of the client, I don't think you'd want this in the list of success codes.

Comment: @stijndepestel The thing is my AWS Environment Health is transitioning from OK to Severe without this Success code added and I found no other alternative.

Comment: Have you implemented and configured a health check endpoint in your API that the beanstalk service can use? Problem is, that it also uses this information for automatic recovering from failures for example, which is a lot less reliable if you add the 400 HTTP error code to the list of success codes.

Comment: @stijndepestel Yes I have tried configuring `Path` to **/index.html** which is present inside templates as well as root directory, and to **/multiple** which is valid url in myenv.region.elasticbeanstalk.com/multiple while keeping Success codes to 200

Comment: @stijndepestel My application uses client-side tests, so 400 errors are frequent as mentioned in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-rules.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console). Therefore, as described in my `Description` setting `Success codes` to **400** or ignoring HTTP 4xx ([https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556599/14408583](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556599/14408583)) can work!!