# Node.js Elastic Beanstalk refuses connections under heavy load (ECONNRESET)

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, scalability

I deployed a simple Node.js Express app to Elastic Beanstalk.

Using the [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) npm package, I hit up the EC2 instance directly (bypassing the ELB) with **150 requests per second**, and that's when things started getting hairy.

```
loadtest -c 10 --rps 150 http://{EC2-IP}/
```

The server would reset the connection immediately (`ECONNRESET`), rending the app unreachable. It refused to support more than X concurrent connections.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Upon diving into the EC2 server's logs, I found the following log message spammed across the file:

```
1024 worker_connections are not enough
```

I then understood that I need to tweak the `worker_connections` declaration in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, as well as the increase OS file descriptor limit, since each connection requires 1 file descriptor.

You can check the OS file descriptor limit by running:

```
ulimit -n
```

However, since the instance is managed by Elastic Beanstalk, Amazon asks that we instead make our edits to `/tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#nginx.conf`, which contains the same content as `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, but Amazon knows to copy it over to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` when the deploy completes, as well as tell `nginx` to use the new configuration.

I created an [.ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) file that increases the OS file descriptor limit, as well as the `worker_connections` declaration. Increasing this limit will allow us to support sudden spikes of traffic instead of returning `ECONNRESET`.

Include it with your application when you deploy, in the following path relative to the root directory of your deployed directory:

`.ebextensions/nginx.config`

```
files:
  "/etc/security/limits.conf":
    content: |
      *           soft    nofile          6144
      *           hard    nofile          6144
container_commands:
    01-worker-connections:
        command: "/bin/sed -i 's/worker_connections  1024/worker_connections  6144/g' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#nginx.conf"
```

Comment: How exactly are you consuming 1024 connections while (apparently) testing with a concurrency of only 10?  It seems like there's another problem here that increasing the limit might be masking, or a problem with `loadtest` itself.

Comment: Not sure, but running `loadtest` with --rps 100 instead of --rps 150 was enough to avoid the worker_connections error / connection resets. Also, it's possible that I had other load on the server from API clients when running this test, so they may have contributed to reaching that 1024 worker_connections limit.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You just saved my ass

Comment: This approach failed for me on Dec 5, 2017 with the following error: `Command failed on instance. Return code: 2 Output: /bin/sed: can't read /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#nginx.conf: No such file or directory. container_command 01-worker-connections in .ebextensions/nginx.config failed. ` It seems AWS might work differently now, see [this SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860426/nginx-config-file-overwritten-during-elastic-beanstalk-deployment#answer-45155825) and [these AWS instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html).

Comment: @ConvexMartian interesting, they must have changed something in the recent EB Platform Versions. Thanks for the heads up and workaround.

Comment: This still works on EC2 Linux instances. Funny enough, I was looking for hours for this exact solution and after I solved it through trial and error I came across this post, that exactly addresses the issue ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

modify directly the original copy of the configuration file: thus put (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) instead of (/tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#nginx.conf).