# Get the default EBS loadbalancer nginx config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I'm looking to edit the **`nginx`** config for an **ElasticBeanstalk AWS** setup, created through cloudformation.

How can I view the default **`nginx`** config?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the beanstalk environment is same when creating via UI or via cloudformation, the default nginx config is located in `/etc/nginx`. However to actually edit the file and have the changes persisted, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45155825/1387827)

Comment: How do i ssh into the load balancer to see that dir?