# How to customize nginx config on Node.js Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS EBS. I'm trying to modify etc/nginx/nginx.conf. I just wanted to add a line in `http{ underscores_in_headers on; }` and I'm able to change by accessing the instance with IP using putty. But the problem is that when auto scaling scales the environment with new IP then the line `http{ underscores_in_headers on; }` will  be removed from new instance.

So, I want when server deploy new snapshot/instance has to be similar as the main server or you can say with same configuration.

[I tried to solve my issue with this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860426/nginx-config-file-overwritten-during-elastic-beanstalk-deployment/38420816)

Comment: Have you already seen this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html

Comment: yes, i have seen this but I'm not able to understand. How I have to do this.

Comment: I understand that I need to add configuration file in .ebextensions but  not able what I have to add to this file.

Comment: You can check the nginx directives here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers. You should be able to add the underscores_in_headers option to the server directive that's in the example, or just create a top-level http directive.

Comment: while updating the EBS it is giving error Top level element in configuration file .ebextensions/nginx/nginx.config in application version app-2244-180809_185240 must be a map. Update the top level element in the configuration file.
2018-08-09 13:22:54    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.

Comment: @Derek that helped me a lot thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1
To edit the configuration in AWS ElasticBean of nginx you need to add the configuration file in .ebextensions

to this add folder .ebextensions/nginx/ create proxy.config file

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      underscores_in_headers on;
```

it will start accepting header with underscores.

Step 2

In case if it not accepting header with underscores then access your instance with ssh and run the following command.

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

stack isn't letting me comment because I'm a noobie. Prateek really helped out, just one small modification to his solution for the proxy.config file and it should work! Don't forget to indent /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf: as well! Further info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      underscores_in_headers on;
```